# Android CWAC Camera : Image from front facing camera always mirrored

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

I am using CWAC's camera in an app. Although the demo app seems to work the way I need it to - i.e the image from the front facing camera is not mirrored if I return true from mirrorFFC() in DemoCameraHost.

```
@Override
 public boolean mirrorFFC() {
    return true;
}
```

When I do the exact same thing in my app, for some reason the image from the front facing camera is still mirrored. Clearly I am missing something out, although I am finding it hard to put my finger on it. I have even passed true to the SimpleCameraHost builder in the onCreate of my Camera Fragment class as shown below.

```
cameraHost = new MyCameraHost(getActivity(), useFFC);
    SimpleCameraHost.Builder builder =
            new SimpleCameraHost.Builder(cameraHost).mirrorFFC(true);
    setHost(builder.useSingleShotMode(true).mirrorFFC(true).build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the reason this was happening was I was returning 0.0f  from 
maxPictureCleanupHeapUsage() in my custom camera host. I changed it back to 1.0f and this seems to have fixed the problem.